# Why does the redirection symbol change the behavior of ls?

Tags: linux, bash, unix

So, I have always had doubts about how redirection works in the following situations:

1. I type "ls" and all the filenames are separated by white spaces:

   ```
   test$ touch a b c
   test$ ls
   a b c
   ```
2. I use a ">" to redirect STDOUT to a file:

   ```
   test$ ls > ls.txt
   test$ cat ls.txt 
   a
   b
   c
   ls.txt
   ```

It is interesting to see that the format changes, with the filenames separated by newline characters. It seems that the output is generated by `ls -1`.

Why is the output in the latter case different from that in the former case? Can ls actually see the ">" symbol so it changes its behavior?

Comment: Excellent question. Millions of people have been using `ls` for years and wondering the same thing.

Comment: If you *want* columns in your redirected output, try `ls -C`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`ls` tests its output stream to see whether it is a terminal, and it modifies its behavior depending on that.

This is documented; the `man` page for `ls` documents several things that depend on whether the output is a terminal:

- If the output is a terminal, `-C` (for multi-column output) is a default, otherwise `-1` (one-column) is a default.
- If `-l` or `-s` is used and the output is a terminal, a sum for all file sizes or blocks, respectively, is printed on a line before the listing.
- If the output is a terminal, `-q` is a default. This prints non-graphic characters as “?”. Otherwise, `-v` and `-w` are defaults. I am a bit unclear on the difference between `-v` and `-w`. The documentation I have says `-v` forces “unedited printing of non-graphic characters” and `-w` forces “raw printing of non-printable characters.”

Comment: Essentially, yes. `ls` uses the equivalent of `[ -t 1 ]`, but since `ls` is written in C and not sh, it uses a different construct with the same semantics.

Comment: @YuFu It calls the POSIX function `isatty` (from `unistd.h`), which is presumably also what `test` calls when given the flag `-t`.

Answer (score 3):

It cannot see the symbol (which is interpreted by the shell), but it can find out whether the output is going to a terminal.

In order to organize files nicely into the columns, `ls` needs to know the width of the terminal. When the output device is not a terminal, it just doesn't know how to format its output.

Another nice consequence of this behavior is that you can do things like `ls | wc -l` without worrying about multiple files on the same line. (You still have to worry about file names containing newlines, though.)

Answer (score 2):

`ls` uses an internal variable called `ls_mode` which is different for the 3 ls "type" commands that Gnu coreutils implement. For [ls](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/ls-ls.c), it's `LS_LS`. For [dir](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/ls-dir.c), it's `LS_MULTI_COL` and for [vdir](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/ls-vdir.c), it's `LS_LONG_FORMAT`. The actual [ls program](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/ls.c) indicates that depending on this variable, the output format will change. For `ls`, this is what it says

> If ls_mode is LS_LS,    the output format depends on whether the
>   output    device is a terminal.    This is for the 'ls' program.

This is congruent with your experience of the format changing with output location. If you try the same with `dir`, it won't be though.

Comment: True for GNU ls, not necessarily true for other ls programs with the same behaviour.

Comment: I'm not sure if any other `ls` implementations even have this kind of behaviour. Based on the question, I presume that it's GNU ls that's being talked about.

Comment: IIRC, the ls on "Interactive 386/ix" did the same and that was pre-Linux, but not pre-GNU and most probably did *not* have GNU ls (being as it was a licensed SysV unix, and all).

Comment: Thanks for that. I don't go back that far. :)